# Excel help to get data from SQL for a particular year based on user input

Tags: excel

Hi I am looking to get SQL data based on a query in Excel which needs a year input. i.e. My sql query will be as follows:

select Col1,Col2,Col3 from Table where year(Col1) = **[Year entered in Cell A1]**

Is there a way i can input the year in a cell A1 in Excel then get data using the query above where the year is gotten from cell A1. I cannot find "Manage Parameters" in my Excel version so is there aby other way to do this.

Regards

Geeta

Tried finding Manage Parameters but am lost after that.

Comment: Are you try to execute the query via `VBA`? Excel formula can't run SQL statement. If you just try to generate string then could try `="select Col1,Col2,Col3 from Table where year(Col1) = '" & A1 & "'"`

Comment: Hi Harun  currently not trying VBA. However i would be glad to use VBA but need help with that. what is the syntax to prompt for a year and then use the year value in my query in VBA? Regards